# Has anybody built a C-file for verifying the code-checking tools for MISRA-2004?

Tags: verification, lint, static-code-analysis, misra

We are using PC-Lint for code-checking our sources for compliance with MISRA-2004. As this is a safety-relevant project and we're heading for a certificate by TUV, we need to show proof for our confidence in the tool (they don't accept anything like "I used it many times").

Our aim is to have a complete set of negative tests, checking the tool for each rule of the MISRA-2004 set by breaking it and forcing an error or warning by the tool.

Has anybody already done this and are you willing to share your  result/C-code?

Comment: Good luck trying to get PC-lint "qualified".  Which standard are you aiming for qualification against (IEC 61508, IEC 26262, DO-178 etc)

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any comprehensive test suites for MISRA compliance but you can download the MISRA "Exemplar Suite" from MISRA's [website](http://www.misra.org.uk/).  You need to register (which is free) and then you can download the suite in the "MISRA C Resources" section.  The suite is not exhuastive but it contains a lot of examples and is a good starting point for creating your own tests.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what it's worth in your case, but I know Gimpel has compliance charts for both MISRA 1998 and 2004. These charts list the rules, state whether Lint can verify rule compliance or not, and provide a comment illustrating why or how.

If you are interested, you can find it [here for MISRA:2004](http://gimpel.com/html/misra2.pdf). There's a version for [MISRA 1998](http://gimpel.com/html/misra1.pdf) as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is one good tool for that - QA-C MISRA

Comment: Please disclose that you work for the company which provides this product when answering in the future.